# Appcelerator login API getting error in response Unexpected identifier

Tags: ios, appcelerator, arrowdb

I am using `Appcelerator  iCloud·Cloud.Users.login·API` its callback is giving me following response:

```
{"success":false,"error":true,"message":"JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier \"An\""}
```

I am stuck on the things and not able to move forward, Our live App users on App Store  are also affected from this.

Problem comes when we open Appcelerator Titanium project from `Xcode` and build the app from there and run on iOS simulator or device.

Here is the code which I am using:

```
Cloud.Users.login({
    login : userId,
    password : password,
}, function(e) {
    //alert(e);
    Ti.API.info("In success ....Cloud.Users.login..");
    Ti.API.info('response from login service'+JSON.stringify(e));
    if (e.success) {
        Ti.API.info('User successfully login');
    } else if (e.error) {
        Ti.API.info(e.message);
        _activityIndicator.hide();
        alertWin.close();           
    }
    //button.show();
});
```

In my case its going in else part because of response which I provided `"success":false` in the JSON which I am getting in callback function from Appcelerator cloud API.

Help me to resolve this error I am getting in callback.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.